# "Not a Red Herring"

Tags: riddle

*Sorry if this is too easy, it is my first post on Puzzling.SE*

> I am an iconic brand
>
> For a famous company
>
> Who prefixes their products with I.

Comment: Usually hints are added only after a puzzle has gone unsolved for a while. You don't need to add so many hints from the off; let the puzzle stand on its own and edit in hints to help people get it if they don't in the beginning.

Comment: Also, this doesn't really seem to be much of a riddle - it's just a direct description of an object. There's not really much to 'figure out' here.

Answer (score 2):

This was a very easy riddle:

> APPLE.

The riddle itself doesn't even have much "riddlish" content (wordplay, metaphor, cryptic stuff): it's just a straightforward description.

> For anyone who's heard of the iPod, iPhone, etc., "company prefixing their products with I" will bring the answer to mind right away.

Comment: In fact, it could be ‘solved’ with the last sentence. But it’s not really solving.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur I'm not sure why you seem to think I didn't do exactly that? I've now removed the hint explanations from my answer since you removed the hints themselves from the question.